# How to get visible rectangle in jetpack compose with TopAppBar using a library module

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I need to get the visible rectangle of the app using a library module.
But I can't get the correct visible rectangle with Jetpack compose with TopAppBar.

In Android view with ActionBar, it was possible to obtain it using the following method.

```kotlin
val contentView = activity.findViewById<ViewGroup>(android.R.id.content)
val appVisibleRect = Rect()
contentView.getGlobalVisibleRect(appVisibleRect)
android.util.Log.d("TAG", "appVisibleRect:$appVisibleRect")
```

When executed with Jetpack compose with TopAppBar, it seems that the TopAppBar part is included in the visible rectangle.

Log with Pixel 6

- Android view: `appVisibleRect:Rect(0, 275 - 1080, 2337)`
- Jetpack compose: `appVisibleRect:Rect(0, 128 - 1080, 2337)`

Is there a way to get the correct visible rectangle excluding the TopAppBar rectangle part in Jetpack compose?